# Push/Pull errors with setting up Git locally using SmartGit

Tags: git, version-control, smartgit

I would like to start using DVCS with Git for a project on my local PC. It's a private project and is to allow me to keep track of changes and versions, and in the future allow outside developers to contribute to the project. 
For now though I'd like to just stick with a local setup.
I'm using SmartGit as my git client.

---

This has been my setup process:

1. Open SmartGit -> Repository -> Add or Create...
2. Add path to my current project folder
3. Select project in repositories pane
4. Stage (all files) -> Commit
5. Branch is set as 'master'

I'd like this to be my central repository, for files to be pushed to, which will be backed up.

Now to create my working repository:

1. Repository -> Clone -> Local Git repository -> Path to the repo I just created
2. Include Submodules, fetch all Heads and Tags

My new repo is now created.

---

Now testing a change to push to the central repo:

1. Navigate to a text file in the working repo (in the repo pane) and open and edit it.
2. Save changes -> Stage -> Commit and Push:

Error:

```
Error not all refs have been pushed -> 'master' rejected (non-fast-forward)
```

Following my research I try this:

1. In the working repo Pull -> Rebase (The recommended way following the tool-tip)
2. Fetch from Path/To/Central/Repo
3. Pull

Now to retry:

1. Push -> Current branch 'master'

Again:

```
Error not all refs have been pushed -> 'master' rejected (non-fast-forward)
```

I now try to fix the error:

1. (working repo) Merge -> master 'Changes' -> Create Merge-Commit -> Fast-Forward

Message:

```
"Already up-to-date"
```

2. Merge -> master 'Changes' -> Create Merge-Commit

Again:

```
"Already up-to-date"
```

I then try and pull from the central repo:

1. (central repo) Pull -> Set remote -> Path/To/Working/Repo
2. Can't Pull can only Fetch

Still same error when I now try and push the changes.

I'm struggling to find out how to push to my central repo.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haven't worked with any git gui clients, I find it's harder to work with git and slower. Try http://msysgit.github.io/. Open git bash to your git repo folder, and run `$ git fetch`, `$ git merge --no-ff origin/master`. You should then be able to push (if no conflicts in merge). `$ git push origin master`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspect is that your local `master` might not be tracking `origin/master`. Also, your central repository should be *bare*, hence I'd recommend to start over again:

1. Make sure your central repository is bare. Therefore, create a new repository using `git init --bare' from command line.

With SmartGit:

2. Create a clone from your central repository, using **Clone**. This will issue a warning like `warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.`
3. Move your existing sources/whatever into the clone and **Commit**. This will automatically put you onto `master`.
4. Finally, invoke **Push** and confirm to **Configure** tracking between `master` and `origin/master`.

Comment: This seems to have worked thanks! If I navigate to the central repository that I created as bare, it contains no files. But running 'git ls-tree -r master' on the folder lists the files as being present, is this normal git behaviour?

Comment: *Bare* means that the repository has no working tree. You may open the **Log** on the bare repository, though. Here, in the **Files** view you may toggle to show *unchanged* files which should give you the same output as `git ls-tree -r <sha>`

Answer (score 0):

What version of Git are you using?  Prior to Git v2.0, the default behavior is to push ALL branches to the remote when doing a push.  It could be that a branch other than the one you are on is out of date with the remote.

If you are below 2.0 and you have any other branches that could be out of date, try typing this from a command line:

```
git config push.default simple
```

Which will tell Git to only push the branch on which you currently reside.  Then try another push and see if that fixes the issue.